# Not open emulator in Android studio

Tags: android, windows, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have a problem, I changed the profile on my windows computer and my android studio stopped working, I already uninstalled it and cleared all the registry, but I still have a problem.

When opening one of my projects, the emulators already created do not appear.

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8srR.png)

I only see the option to open the emulator, but when I send the application, it tells me that it cannot find a connected device.

[Emulador Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8hLz.png)

The SDK if it is correctly referenced.

[SDK ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1auBv.png)

Thank you can you help me.

If I open the android studio as administrator it shows me the emulators but it disconnects them and gives me many errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can try running `flutter doctor` in a terminal to see if that helps. creating a new android virtual device could also fix things.